# Using lambda sort function to sort a tuple of strings by each tuples combined value

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, tuples

I have a list of tuples, where each tuple(a,b) represents the height of an object a*b:

```
L = [("3m", "5cm"), ("10m", "77cm"), ("1m", "82cm"), ("1m", "74cm"), ("11m", "50cm")]
```

Now, I want to sort this list based on height using a lambda sort function. The output is supposed to look as follows:

```
L = [("1m", "74cm"), ("1m", "82cm"), ("3m", "5cm"), ("10m", "77cm"), ("11m", "50cm")]
```

The follwing is what I tried, but I am getting errors:

```
L.sort(key= lambda x: 100 * int(x[0][0:-2]) + int(x[1][0:-3]))
```

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is due to an incorrect slicing of the strings. It is always useful to break down these problems into smaller parts. When slicing the first string:

```
print(L[0][0][0:-2])
''
```

This returns an empty string. Following your notation it should actually be `L[0][0][0:-1]`, which can be simplified to `L[0][0][:-1]`. This is because with python slice notation `a[start:stop]`, the last element of a slice is not included. I suggest you check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) so you have a better understanding of how slice notation works. So you need:

```
sorted(L, key = lambda x: int(x[0][:-1])*100 + int(x[1][:-2]))

[('1m', '74cm'),
 ('1m', '82cm'),
 ('3m', '5cm'),
 ('10m', '77cm'),
 ('11m', '50cm')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your slice indices are off; the end index is exclusive, so you wanted to slice to index `-1` and `-2` respectively, making it:

```
L.sort(key=lambda x: 100 * int(x[0][:-1]) + int(x[1][:-2]))
```

I also omitted the start index (since it defaults to zero for forward slices anyway). Another solution would be to `rstrip` so you're not performing explicit slicing with magic numbers:

```
L.sort(key=lambda x: 100 * int(x[0].rstrip('m')) + int(x[1].rstrip('cm')))
```

Note that `rstrip` will strip *runs* of any of the provided characters, so this might misbehave if you had values that didn't end with the expected `m` and `cm`, but then, the magic slicing would silently misbehave more often, so this would still be an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace` to `m` and `cm` or any sister method like `.strip("cm")`

```
 L.sort(key= lambda x: 100 * int(x[0].replace('m','')) + int(x[1].replace('cm','')))
```

Comment: Negative indices remove the need to know the length; it's brittle, but it would work if the inputs reliably ended in only `m` or `cm` and the end index is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert each tuple into a single integer; a tuple of integers will suffice (assuming, alas, that you don't have any weird heights like `("1m", "105cm")`).

```
L.sort(key=lambda x: (int(x[0].strip("cm")), int(x[1].strip("cm"))))
```

Lists sort the same as tuples, so you can simplify this with a list comprehension.

```
L.sort(key=lambda p: [int(x.strip("cm")) for x in p])
```

Both tuples and lists compare lexicographically: one element at a time, with the first pair of non-equal elements determining the result.

Comment: I would not have expected that; might be an implementation detail based on how many name lookups have to occur.

Comment: My bad, it is the other way around. Converting to integers is about 0.000023 seconds faster than using the list comprehension. I still appreciate you explanation though, how tuples and lists compare.